# tastypie : model has an empty attribute - reverse relationship

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am getting this error using tastypie and trying to get the ToManyField to work (it should not return any null values):

```
error: "The model 'Feature: Feature object' has an empty attribute 'featureloc_set' and doesn't allow a null value."
```

These are the models:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feature'

class Featureloc(models.Model):
    featureloc_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, related_name="featureloc_feature")
    srcfeature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, blank=True, null=True, related_name="featureloc_srcfeature")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'featureloc'
```

These are the resources:

```
class BFeatureResource(ModelResource):
    featurelocs = fields.ToManyField('api.BFeaturelocResource2', 'featureloc_set', full=True)
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'bands'
        queryset = Feature.objects.all()

class BFeaturelocResource2(ModelResource):
    feature = fields.ForeignKey(BFeatureResource, 'feature')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'featurelocs'
        queryset = Featureloc.objects.all()
```

Is it confused as there are 2 ForeingKey fields in Featureloc to Feature (i.e. feature and srcfeature)? What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Now have this working by using a related_name on the ForeignKey that matches the attribute in the ToManyField:

```
featurelocs = fields.ToManyField('api.BFeaturelocResource2', 'fl_feature', full=True)
```

and

```
feature = fields.ForeignKey(BFeatureResource, 'feature', related_name='fl_feature')
```